# ¿Porque httpd en ArchLinux no me lee archivos php?

Tags: apache

Buenas tardes amigos de stackoverflow.

Tengo un problema con mi apache (httpd) en archlinux ya que monto una serie de archivos para poder desarrollar en mi entorno de trabajo y solamente me muestra texto en htmlo y php plano. Realmente no se si tendre problemas con mis modulos dentro de la configuración del servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que activar los módulos de php para Apache, configurar Apache para que lea los .php y, por supuesto, no te olvides de instalar php :P

No olvides tampoco que para acceder a php tienes que entrar por el navegador:
localhost/index.php (En tu caso, los nombres de los archivos que le hayas dado) o sustituir localhost por la IP correspondiente.

Comment: el php esta instalado, y no se como activar el modulo desde el archivo de configuración.

Comment: A ver si ahí puedes encontrar algo que te ayude.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server_(Espa%C3%B1ol)

Pero sobretodo no olvides entrar por el navegador a localhost/directoriodelarchivo.php, de lo contrario te saldrá texto plano.

Después de eso, por supuesto añade que apache lea los .php, que puede que por defecto traiga solo html.

Cada cambio que hagas, reinicia apache y prueba por navegador si funciona, pero no ejecutes el archivo desde el propio sistema, entra desde navegador a la ruta.

Comment: Para activar los módulos del archivo httpd.conf tan solo localizar el modulo que necesites y quitar la almohadilla #

Comment: Correcto. Pero creo recordar que también había que editar algo en el php.ini. Hace mucho que no lo hago y solo lo he hecho en Windows y Ubuntu.

Comment: Le anexe este modulo LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so pero aun asi no me reconose nada de php y eso que en mi arch esta instalado valga la redundancia el php.

Comment: @J.M.C Hermano gracias por tu ayuda me ayudo a resolver el problema y era que habia que anexar esto:

Bajo <IfModule mime_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

Comment: Eso, te dije también que tenías que agregar la extensión .php para que los leyese :) me alegro de haber servido de ayuda ! :D